# problem installing ADT for eclipse

Tags: android

I have installed Eclipse on my laptop - it seems to be the Indigo version.  The I tried to Install new software.  I entered the https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse url into the Work With box.   After pending resolved itself I then pressed next and now have a view of the items and an error saying that a shared profile (maven) is missing.   I am stumped as to what to do next!!

Comment: same here. Check my comment on the m2eclipse

Comment: hi , change https:// with http://

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK works fine with Indigo, and providing you started from a clean Indigo installation, the update site you mentioned should work just fine.

I would suggest downloading a fresh copy of Indigo, hold off installing any other plugins and trying again with that update site. Works fine on my windows 7 machine.

(it's also a good practice not to re-use existing eclipse installations for Android development. IMHO its better to setup a dedicated eclipse installation for it to ensure that other plugins / dependencies mess up the install).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The installation was on a new laptop so there wasnt any previou stuff there.  It says it cant find 'org.maven.ide.eclipse'  I have Eclipse Galileo on my pc and am developing with that.   The laptop installation is so I can carry on working away from base.   Will the work I have already done on the Galileo setup be useable on Indigo.   When I downloaded I did not choose Indigo it's simply what arrived.

Comment: I've looked at the m2 link.  I dont think I need a Project Management tool.  If I download eclipse again is there any way to avoid this being required?

Comment: No it's not required. I just verified it with a clean Indigo installation. I just pointed it out as it might help you resolve the dependency issue you were having.

Comment: I am getting a bit dizzy now!!  The eclipse download doesnt seem to have an installer - I unzipped into c:\program files.   so there was no uninstaller and I had to delete the eclipse folder to clear the way.  I've reinstalled Indigo following the same procedure and get the same problem.   Looks like I've got something fundamental wrong in the first and second installations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Instead of just picking some other versions od ADK and hoping the best, I recommend to take the whole Eclipse + Android set from Google. With this you will get co-working peaces of your IDE. It's not very techy way solve this problem- but it WORKS! Just remember to uninstall your old Eclipse first.

So from here you will get the whole package:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

""With a single download, the Eclipse ADT bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps:

-Eclipse + ADT plugin

-Android SDK Tools

-Android Platform-tools

-A version of the Android platform

-A version of the Android system image for the emulator""